# Generate 3 digits numbers according to specific constraints

Tags: c++

If I take 3 numbers A B C with 3 digits each (between 100-999) and do :

A + B = C

If all nine digits used are non zero and different from each other ( 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9) then the sum of the digits of C will always be 18.

```
ex : 152 + 487 = 639   -----> 6+3+9 = 18 
     357 + 462 = 819 = -----> 8+1+9 = 18
```

I need my program to show all cases of numbers A,B and C that respect this relation. I am unsure how to tackle this problem. I was thinking of either using an outer for loop and a inner for loop or using the rand function but I am unsure how to give the necessary conditions to any of these methods.

Comment: Your example is only using 2 numbers.  Where is the third?

Comment: I am sorry meant to write A + B = C instead of A + B + C. I edited that. In my examples C is 639 and 819 respectively

Comment: @AnatolyS: well, for starters, 10 is incorrect.

Comment: @Karoly Horvath it was hard day for me, but 10 is correct. So loop looks like that for(int i = 1; i<10; i++) for(int j=1; j<10; j++)for(int k=1; k<10; k++). It'is good start point

Comment: @Karoly Horvath 10 is open upper bound of the range [1-10)

Comment: @AnatolyS: tl;dr: I don't how is that going to work. Seriously, post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach would be to go through all permutations of "123456789" using [`std::next_permutation`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) and check that the first 3 digits plus the second 3 digits minus the last 3 digits equals 0.  Something like:

```
int main() 
{
    std::string numbers = "123456789";
    int a, b, c;
    do
    {
        a = std::stoi(numbers.substr(0, 3));
        b = std::stoi(numbers.substr(3, 3));
        c = std::stoi(numbers.substr(6, 3));
        if (a + b == c)
            std::cout << a << " + " << b << " = " << c << "\n";
    } while (std::next_permutation(numbers.begin(), numbers.end()));
}
```

Comment: Yeah that was my idea as well. I'm just wondering, since you're not the first one doing this.. so, why do people rewrite `a + b == c` to `a + b - c == 0`?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath You know I didn't even think about it, it was just what my mind concluded.  I'll change it as `a + b == c` matches the OP's requirements.

Comment: Technically, both match it.

Comment: @NathanOliver What header do I need to include to be able to use next_permutation ? I am trying with #include <algorithm> but next_permutation remains undefined

Comment: @student for my example you need string and algorithm

Comment: @NathanOliver Nvm my above comment i fixed that. But how can I make it so cases are not repeated. For example 219 + 664 = 873 and then 654 + 219 = 873

Comment: Maybe limiting the permutations by half?  Keep a counter and once you hit enough permutations to cover half of the total end the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Enumerate all the 9! (=362880) permutations of the 9 digits, then for each permutation check whether it meets the requirements.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9    one permutation
----- ----- -----
  A     B     C      chunked to these numbers (simple base10 math)
```

For generating the permutations you can use [`next_permutation`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation).

Answer (score 0):

1. Find all 3-digit number pairs whose sums of digits are 18.
2. Add the numbers; discard if sum not equal to 999.
3. Discard entries where A1 == B2 and A2 == B1

Optimizations:

- There is only one unique number B for each number A such that A + B == 999.
- For every number A and B the differcence between the current A and the next A and the current B And the next B is always greater than 8.

---

Use if conditions for the required mathematic conditions. Simple as that.

Iterate through all the 3-digit number pairs by using a for-loop or paralleize by using async

I'm on mobile so I can't code; I'll edit this if you need more.